# Trigger ESP8266 reset pin on broken connection

Tags: esp8266, sleep, reset

I have an ESP8266 which I wish to place in deep sleep until a reed switch senses a door being opened. The ESP8266 is woken from deep sleep by briefly raising the RESET pin high.

In my original design, I thought that raising the RESET pin would wake the device instantly. Instead raising the pin holds the device in a reset state until it goes low again. This means that the 8266 currently wakes after the door is opened and closed again.

I'm looking for a way to briefly trigger the RESET pin after the reed switch connection is broken with minimal additional hardware, and minimal power drain while in deep sleep. I can use either NC or NO Reed switches.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the reset pin is HIGH for normal run, it must be pulled LOW for reset. I don't know what is the state of the pin in deep sleep

Comment: A simple capacitor can be used to convert a level change into a short pulse - just like the Arudino UNO etc use for the DTR->RESET signal.

Comment: why not power it through the switch and seleep once the message is sent? that uses no power in standby.